# Rosie #386 vs Rosie fishing Amiibo Cards

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons, amiibo, animal-crossing

What is the difference between these two Rosie Animal Crossing Amiibo cards (English versions)?

This one is #386. The code in the bottom right reads *386-QK-AOE*:

[image]

This one has her fishing and has the Animal Crossing Amiibo logo instead of a number. The code in the bottom right reads *404-RD-AOE*:

[image]

Are they the same character? Do they behave the same way in games? Why are they different?